# In Sprite Kit, when I am spawning nodes, why do they all appear on the top right of the screen?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

MainPlayer is the main ball in the center, and I want the blue enemy nodes to spawn randomly on each side, but they are all appearing in the top right. I am pretty sure this code is correct, and I cannot get it to work. It seems like they are spawning in the right place, but it is just scaled to the top right for some reason.

```
func Enemies() {
        let xPos = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 0, secondNum: frame.width )

        let Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
        Enemy.zPosition =  -1.0
        Enemy.size = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)

        Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
        Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Smallball | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
        Enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Smallball | PhysicsCategory.MainBall

        let randomNumber = arc4random() % 4 + 1

        switch randomNumber {
        case 0:
            Enemy.position.x = 0
            var positionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            Enemy.position.y = CGFloat(positionY)
            self.addChild(Enemy)
            break

        case 1:
            Enemy.position.y = 0
            var positionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            Enemy.position.x = CGFloat(positionX)
            self.addChild(Enemy)
            break

        case 2:
            Enemy.position.y = frame.size.height
            var positionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            Enemy.position.x = CGFloat(positionX)
            self.addChild(Enemy)
            break

        case 3:
            Enemy.position.x = frame.size.width
            var positionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            Enemy.position.y = CGFloat(positionY)
            self.addChild(Enemy)
            break

        default:
            break
        }

        Enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(xPos), y: self.frame.size.height / 2)
        Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 7)
        Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        addChild(Enemy)

        Enemy.run(SKAction.move(to: MainPlayer.position, duration: 3))
    }
```

This is the result of my code, and obviously, I just let it spawn instead of move to the ball because I wanted to show the weird spawning locations.

[image]

Comment: The ancorPoint of your scene is likely 0.5,0.5, which means that 0.0,0.0 is at the center of the scene. So to spawn node on the left from the red ball, you should spawn nodes between -scene.size.width/2 ( not the minus sign).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    Enemy.zPosition =  -1.0
    Enemy.size = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: 20.0)
    Enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Enemy
    Enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Smallball | PhysicsCategory.MainBall
    Enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Smallball | PhysicsCategory.MainBall

    Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```

Remove the code after break except `Enemy.run(SKAction.move(to: MainPlayer.position, duration: 3))`
Also, try removing the +1 after arc4random